# How to route every mysql query through a function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have developed a project under which several sql query have been used. Now I want to monitor some query in order increase security. So I want every query to be passed through a function first. As there are too many queries so I can not go back and edit every file and query. Is there a way that I can trap into queries before they are sent to mysql server?

Comment: Which are these queries, select queries or updates

Comment: in Oracle this would be row-level-security or fine-grained-access control.  I would first investigate privileges.

Answer (score 3):

There are four ways to accomplish this depending on what you are using, the last being the much more reliable.

## **The General Query Log**

MySQL provides a mechanism to log just about everything that the `mysqld` process is doing, via the general query log. As you described in your question you probably do not have persistent connections, so you will need to either:

- Enable the MySQL general query log when the `mysqld` process is started, with the [`--log[=file_name]`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log)

  - Set a global/session variable with `SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'`.

Fore more information about the general query log, see the [MySQL 5.1 reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).

## **Using `sed` (or manually!)**

This technique involves creating a a new function, and renaming all of the `mysqli_*` function calls to call another function.

Presuming your newly created function is named `proxy_query()`, you can use `sed` to traverse through all files and change them automatically:

```
sed i '.bck' 's/mysqli_query/proxy_query/'
```

The `-i` paramater specifies that the file should be edited in place, and that a copy should be made of the original file and have a `.bck` extension appended.

## **The `runkit` extension**

I must admit that I'm being naive here, and that I haven't used this particular extension before - but it is possible to rename functions with this PECL extension. 
The requirements for this extension can be found here, and note that it is *not* bundled with PHP.

As with above, you can create a proxy function where all calls will go through. Let's assume it's also called `proxy_query`. Usage would go something like this:

```
// rename the function (a very bad idea, really!)
runkit_function_renam('mysqli_connect', 'proxy_super');

function mysqli_query($query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT)
{
    // do something with the SQL in $query
    // .. and call mysqli_query, now proxy_super
    return proxy_super($query, $resultmode);
}
```

I have to note here that **this method is highly discouraged**. You shouldn't ever need to set default PHP functions.

## **Using Pdo/OO-mysqli**

This is the simplest technique, and probably the most reliable as well. If you're using Pdo already, you can simply extend the `\Pdo` class. A similar approach could be used with MySQL Improved(`mysqli`):

```
class MyPdo extends \Pdo
{
    public function query($query [, ... ]) 
    {
        // do something with $query
        return parent::query($query [, ... ]);
    }
}
```

Also note here, that this will only work if you are using Pdo, and if you are able to change the instantiation of the `Pdo` object, to overwrite it to your own class: `MyPdo`.
For more information about the `\Pdo` class, and it's children, see the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: In the same way you can extend `mysqli`

Comment: indeed. forgot that mysqli can be used as OO. :(

Comment: I am not using PDO. I am using mysql_query()

Comment: The answer still applies, see the first three suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor incoming queries using SQL profiler can be an excellent way to gather information on what's going on inside SQL without passing it all through a single function or procedure.

Comment: I want to intentionally pass it through a function as I want to restrict its execution.

Comment: What restrictions do you intend to impose on it's execution?
It sounds to me like you should be using permissions as opposed to what would essentially be a control function

Comment: I want to restrict the result set of each query based on its user restriction.